# Remove specific line by line number from several files

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, vi

I want to remove the second line of several files (there are like 200). All files begin with Glo so i want to do a command or a shell to remove all second lines for that file:

Example:

```
Glo1:
1 AAA
2 BBB
3 the third line

Glo2:
1 DDD
2 RRR
3 the third line
```

What i want is to delete only the second line, so files will look like this:

```
Glo1:
1 AAA
2 the third line

Glo2:
1 DDD
2 the third line
```

Regards!

Comment: Must it be done with vi/vim? Are you open to other shell solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned using a shell:

```
sed -i '3d' Glo*
```

Comment: Or a glob `sed '3d' Glo*`

Comment: But you'll also need `-i` to modify them in place. This will output to STDOUT otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, just realized I was missing in-place editing.

Comment: Edits files in-place. Reads their data, changes it according to its sed command, and writes the changed directly back into the files. Use with caution if you do not know what you are doing. :)